# Apache FallbackResource Configuration

Tags: php, linux, apache, php-7, apache2.4

I am trying to port a PHP application from Windows IIS to Linux (Debian) with Apache web server (v2.4).  I successfully changed my Document Root to `/code/wwwroot`, and am using the config file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` instead of `.htaccess` for my configuration (in the Apache 2.4 docs it says to use the config files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` if you have access to server configuration files, which I do).  This is what I am using for my configuration:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
      DocumentRoot /code/wwwroot
      <Directory /code/wwwroot>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        FallbackResource /start.php
      </Directory>
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

This works almost exactly how I would expect.  When files found in `/code/wwwroot/` are requested, they are served.  If the file/path requested does not exist, `start.php` is run and returned.  For example, if my request is `localhost/gadgasd.html`, etc, it internally redirects to `start.php`.  However, for files with `.php` extensions that do not exist in Document Root, I am getting 404's.  For example, if the request is `localhost/gadgasd.php`, I get a 404 directly from Apache (I was hoping to handle 404's in my code rather than Apache).  This behavior is strictly limited to files with `.php` extensions that do not exist in Document Root.  I am very confused about this behavior.  I have setup the correct packages for using php with apache (`apt-get install -y php libapache2-mod-php`) and the `FallbackResource` rule works for all other file extensions.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Apache and has an open issue tracker [here](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52403). There is also a workaround provided.

**EDIT:** In case the link ever dies, the workaround is to use the old `mod_rewrite` approach as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond /var/www/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond /var/www/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) start.php
```

Comment: The _TestString_ (first) argument to the `RewriteCond` directive should not be prefixed with `/var/www/` when used in a _directory_ context (such as here and in the linked bug tracker), since it should already be part of the value of `REQUEST_FILENAME` (unlike when used in a _server_ context). `/var/www/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` will never exist and the request will _always_ be rewritten to `start.php`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that the default mod_php configuration (`/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/phpX.conf`) doesn't appear to check if the file exists before passing the request to the PHP handler. This can easily be added by changing:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

to

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
    <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </If>
</FilesMatch>
```

`<FilesMatch/>` doesn't appear to check if the file exists like you might expect, this means all requests that end with `.php`, `.phtml` and `.phar` are blindly passed to the php handler.

It's worth noting that this might have a performance impact as Apache must have to check on disk if the file is there but I would speculate that the difference would be negligible in almost all cases.